# Allow commenting on work items but not editing

Tags: azure-devops

My company is moving to DevOps and Azure Boards from our previous environment in JIRA and we've encountered a very big issue with permissions.

At the moment, we have configured various Areas to support our development teams; we also have an Area dedicated to the Product team, where business requirements are first input and then reviewed. Each team has permission to edit work items in its own Area and it can't edit work items in other areas.

So, basically this is our structure:

- Engineering: the main Area of the project; only administrators can edit work items
- Engineering\Mobile: child area for the Mobile team; only members of the Mobile team and administrators can edit work items
- Engineering\Backend: child area for the Backend team; only members of the Backend team and administrators can edit work items
- Engineering\Device: child area for the Device team; only members of the Device team and administrators can edit work items
- Engineering\Product: child area to review business requirements that are then moved to the appropriate area; everybody can edit work items

Now we're trying to give anybody from any team the permission to comment (aka. use the "Discussion" section) a work item regardless of the Area where it is, but it looks like the ability to comment is strictly related to the permission of editing the work item… In other words, we haven't been able to enable the Discussion section without giving the permission to edit a work item, which isn't ideal.

Is there a way to enable the Discussion section for anybody while keeping editing restricted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not able to do this in Azure DevOps at present.

Unless you give the users permission "edit work items in node" permission, otherwise he will not be able to comment in the discussion field separately.

There is already a user voice here--[Add support for for/not rules in the inherited process model](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365854/field-level-security-permissions-1.html)

According to our PM's reply:

> We currently do not have any plans **enable field level security**. But we
>   will continue to track this suggestion. If we begin to see more votes
>   we will take it under further consideration.

You could vote that ticket and track the process. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: That's a bummer. Anyway, thanks for the reply! We'll manage this in some other way.

Comment: @MrAsterisco This feature has been released. See release notes for details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-156-update#azure-boards-1

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT this doesn't actually address the user's original concern though, at least not cleanly.  They want to have discussion allowed, but not editing the work item otherwise.  However, this user voice only allows blocking particular fields when not in a group.  Now, I suppose you could make a rule for every single field on the work item for every single different area, but that's really not a viable solution at scale.

Answer (score 6):

well they finally added this as a permission in 2023-02-07 release!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2023/sprint-216-update#new-save-comments-permission

yay! better way way way way later than never i guess